# Using above par zero coupon bond to build a zero coupon curve

Tags: fixed-income, yield-curve, bootstrapping, zero-coupon

Should I discard bonds above par (zero coupon bond with market price over par value) when I build a zero coupon curve?

Most of the academic textbooks use bonds below par as inputs to build Zero Coupon Curve (to show bootstrapping methodology). So, I wonder what happen whit bonds above par value. Should I use them?